# How To: Dynamically Creating the XML file content and sending as a text file in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

hi there i am working on an asp.net web page that first lets users to enter required values to indicated textfields and then generate a new text file according to the data given by the user.

I want to let users receive a "Result.xml" file when they click on "get file" button.

i've searched for that info, i know it must have an easy solution but by now i am out of luck (i must be tired). i tried the following code but it didnt worked:

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.Tables.Add("TEST");
 ds.writexml("test.xml");
 Response.TransmitFile("test.xml");
```

but the program says it couldnt find any file. also i dont want to "write" a physical file to the server, i just want to send the contents of the dataset as "test.xml"

Please help, 
Thanks for spending your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well assuming you are able to populate your DataSet properly, you should be able to use  [DataSet.WriteXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) as in your example to write to a MemoryStream, then dump the file to the HTTP response without ever hitting your server's disk.

I'm a little rusty with C#, this example is from VB, so please take syntax with a grain of salt:

```
    System.IO.MemoryStream objStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add("TEST");
    ds.WriteXml(objStream);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=File.xml");
    Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.ToArray());
    Response.End();
```

Comment: this solution looks like the best choice for my question. i will let you know if it works when i test it tomorrow thank you for the answer

Comment: Combining this with the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407295/saving-xml-files-from-a-dataset-through-asp-net provides a simplification - use the MemoryStream at hand, in Response.Outstream; i.e. after setting header, ds.WriteXml(Response.Outstream);

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to write a XML file to the Client machine. Here we 
write the contents directly into the `Response.OutputStream` using the `XmlTextWriter`:

```
try
{           
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=FileName.xml");
    XmlTextWriter xWriter = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    xWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xWriter.WriteStartDocument();
    //Create Parent element
    xWriter.WriteStartElement("Parent");
    //Create Child elements
    xWriter.WriteStartElement("Element");
    xWriter.WriteElementString("ID", "1001");
    xWriter.WriteElementString("Name", "John");
    xWriter.WriteElementString("Age", "22");
    xWriter.WriteEndElement();

    //End writing top element and XML document
    xWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xWriter.WriteEndDocument();
    xWriter.Close();
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you work with files in Asp.Net you should use Server.MapPath. If you use relative paths your code will probably try to write to the IIS folder and might (hopefully) not be allowed to do so. So instead of using "test.xml" you should use

```
Server.MapPath("~/text.xml")
```

The tilde expands to your web application folder. That said it's a bad idea to store the file to disc. The Response object has an OutputStream which can be used to send data to the browser. You should write your data set directly into that stream. So no file has to be written to disc, you don't have to care about paths and your code will also work with multiple concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the link link to an IHTTPHandler with the folowing code:

```
public class YourHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", XML_FileName));
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("MyFile.xml"));
        Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```