# Saving XML files from a dataSet through ASP.NET

Tags: xml, database, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I have two code samples, once takes a table from my database, puts it into a DataSet and then saves the DataSet and an XML file to my desktop.

The other code saves a file from a webpage. What I would like to do is combine these two code examples so that I can save my XML file through the internet.

Here are the samples:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
            DataSet questionSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(questionSet, "Questions");

            questionSet.WriteXml("../../../../../Users/User/Desktop/MyTest");
```

This successfully saves my table as an XML document and saves it to my Desktop.

The [code sample from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478985.aspx#aspnet-jspmig-downloadinganduploading_topic6) for saving files through ASP.NET

```
System.String filename = "myFile.txt";

                   Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

                   // initialize the http content-disposition header to
                   // indicate a file attachment with the default filename
                   // "myFile.txt"
                   System.String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\"" + filename +
                      "\"";
                   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);

                   // transfer the file byte-by-byte to the response object
                   System.IO.FileInfo fileToDownload = new
                      System.IO.FileInfo("C:\\downloadJSP\\DownloadConv\\myFile.txt");
                   Response.Flush();
                   Response.WriteFile(fileToDownload.FullName);}
```

This successfully saves a file through my browser.

As far as I understand it, it seems that `.WriteXml` creates a the file from the dataSet. Is there a way to throw that file at the other code and tell the browser to download the `.WriteXml` file instead?

All of this code looks almost like magic to me, but then again, it's .NET, which is known for its pixie dust!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you need is this:

```
questionSet.WriteXml(Response.OutputStream);
```

You still want to set the content type, but you don't need to mess with the file system to do this.