# Send XML File to client

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have an XDocument object that needs to be downloaded by the client. This xml will be generated on page_load and then sent to the user as a download.

I cant figgure out how to send the object to the client without having an acctual file.
Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806675/how-to-dynamically-creating-the-xml-file-content-and-sending-as-a-text-file-in (not quite a duplicate but relevant)

Comment: you what the xml to show on the page?

Comment: No the xml will just be generated from a datasource and then be sent to the user as a file for downloading. the xml will not be shown on the page.

Answer (score 0):

As stated i checked [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806675/how-to-dynamically-creating-the-xml-file-content-and-sending-as-a-text-file-in) not quite the same but close enough.

```
Response.Clear(); 
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + DateTime.Now+".xml");
Response.Write(doc.ToString());
Response.End();
```